# Ubuntu 12.04 + RAID0 + Windows 7 not loading

Tags: grub2, raid

I have a PC with 2 Hd (1Tb each) on RAID0. I had a Windows 7 64-bit working for several months.

When I installed the Windows I left a 100GB partition empty to install Ubuntu someday.

I was using Linuxin Virtualbox, but this week I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 in this 100GB partition.

I used the Ubuntu alternate cd, because the 'normal' cd was giving me trouble with the RAID0. GRUB installation always reported a error. After a lot of work I found that I needed to install grub on partition `/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1` (see Bootinfo below).

The Windows installation created a 100Mb boot partition, so I needed to install grub in this partition.

Now I have the Ubuntu working 100% OK.

The problem is, Windows is not booting! The windows option is present on the grub menu, but when I choose the Windows option there is a black screen and after that the grub menu reappears.

Bootinfo:

```
Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 1 for /boot/grub.
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid 
    and looks at sector 1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at 
    this location and looks in partition 1 for /boot/grub.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1: ________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1 and looks at sector 3841862992 
                       of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at 
                       this location and looks for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on 
                       this drive. No errors found in the Boot Parameter 
                       Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grldr /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /grldr

isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid2: ________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3: ________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5: ________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img

isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid6: ________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             206,848 3,686,402,047 3,686,195,200   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3       3,686,402,558 3,907,039,743   220,637,186   5 Extended
Invalid MBR Signature found.
EBR refers to a location outside the hard drive.

/dev/sda2 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda
/dev/sda3 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda

Drive: isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid: 2000.4 GB, 2000404348928 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907039744 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1   *          2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid2            206,848 3,686,402,047 3,686,195,200   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3      3,686,402,558 3,907,039,743   220,637,186   5 Extended
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5      3,686,402,560 3,881,876,479   195,473,920  83 Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid6      3,881,876,992 3,907,039,743    25,162,752  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1 C89C73D19C73B910                       ntfs       Reservado pelo Sistema
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid2 6830883A3088116C                       ntfs       
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5 bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c   ext4       
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid6 7a830a3c-88fb-4cba-80dc-f32e08abfd5b   swap       
/dev/sda                                                isw_raid_member 
/dev/sdb                                                isw_raid_member 
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Windows7x86x64SK

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid
isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1
isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid2
isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3
isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5
isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid6

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5 /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sr0         /media/Windows7x86x64SK  iso9660    (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks)


================= isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1/grldr embedded menu: ==================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

================== isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ==================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="$1"
    if [ "$1" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid3,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbab868a-ea53-4be3-ba7d-2737fe6cb24c
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(sda,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C89C73D19C73B910
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

====================== isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5/etc/fstab: =======================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid6 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

========== isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ===========

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

               =                boot/grub/core.img                             1
               =                boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
               =                boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae           2
               =                boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae           2
               =                boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae              1
               =                boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae              1
               =                initrd.img                                     2
               =                initrd.img.old                                 2
               =                vmlinuz                                        1
               =                vmlinuz.old                                    1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda1


Unknown BootLoader on sda2


Unknown BootLoader on sda3



=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
hexdump: /dev/sda1: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda1: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda2: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda2: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda3: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda3: No such file or directory
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
```

How we can see the Windows part at grub is:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1)" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='(sda,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C89C73D19C73B910
        chainloader +1
    }
```

I tried a lot of combinations at the line:

```
set root='(sda,msdos1)'
```

but no success

I tried to change UUID to the `/dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid2` UUID, but GRUB reports a error.

What should I do?

Comment: As a last resort, if none of teh other optinos are working. You can pop in the windows CD and select repair. I would use this as a last resort becaue i beleive sums tuff mgiht get deleted

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your machine that GRUB is installed in your MBR, replacing windows default installation. If it is that only that you want your windows operating system to start, Then you can just go for repairing the MBR. You can use your windows disk to go into recovery mode and then follow below procedure to repair your MBR and boot.

```
STEP1: Goto windows recovery mode and open up the command prompt there
STEP2: write the following code to accomplish your target:
        x:\sources>bootrec /fixmbr
        x:\sources>bootrec /fixboot
STEP3: Just restart the computer after that and you will loose the GRUB loader and will directly be booted into windows.
```

Now you need to reinstall the grub to make your ubuntu work again. If you have question regarding re-installing the grub, then just let me know in the comments. I will edit the answer with details for it.

Answer (score 0):

Dual booting with the Windows System Partition never worked for me and I'm used to do it different, but while UEFI based systems are continuing to replace BIOS based systems lets try to fix this.

There is a wiki page on [fixing dual booting for UEFI based systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Chainloading_Windows_x86_64_UEFI-GPT) in the Ubuntu Community Documentation. But you probably don't have bootmgfw.efi since you're using a MS DOS partition table, so that won't work. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process) Windows wants to load `bootmgr` first, which should be located at the root of the Windows System Partition.

So mount the partition in Ubuntu and do the following:

```
grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /path/to/windows_system_patition/bootmgr
```

That should return the UUID of the Windows System Partition. Now modify your Grub 2 menu entry for Windows like this:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/mapper/isw_chjbfeec_DougRaid1)" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod fat
        insmod ntfs
        set root='(sda,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root UUID_of_Windows_System_Partition
        chainloader (${root})/bootmgr
    }
```

Replace UUID_of_Windows_System_Partition with the UUID you got from the previous command. Note that I added `insmod fat`, because this partition used to be a FAT partition and the target for the chainloader is the Windows Boot Manager. I can also see a `w7ldr` next to `bootmgr` in my Windows 7 VM, which should be the Windows 7 Bootloader. Make a copy of the menu entry above and replace *bootmgr* with *w7ldr* and try that too. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after you made the edits, but you probably know that. :-)

Hope this works, I wish you good luck.